# Bokeh Python how to interact with radio buttons

Tags: python, bokeh

I have built a scatter plot with an radiobuttongroup on the top. How can I link the widget with the plot? The outcome I want to achieve is like the following:

choose 'one' - only show the dots when their x value equals 1

choose 'two' - only show the dots when their x value equals 2

choose 'three' - only show the dots when their x value equals 3

Here's my code so far:

```
dataset = {'x':[0,1,2],'y':[0,1,2]}

source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dataset)


p2 = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=600, 
            x_range=(-0.1, 2.1), y_range=(-0.1,2.1))

p2.scatter('x', 'y', source=source2, 
          size=15,
          alpha=0.8, 
          line_color=None)

# option
option = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["One", "Two", "Three"], active=0)


show(column(option, p2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you are looking for:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets import RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS

dataset = {'x':[0,1,2],'y':[0,1,2],'x_filter':[0,1,2]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dataset)
p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=600, 
            x_range=(-0.1, 2.1), y_range=(-0.1,2.1))
p.scatter('x', 'y', source=source, 
          size=15, alpha=0.8, line_color=None)

# add callback to control 
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p=p, source=source), code="""

            var radio_value = cb_obj.active;
            var data = source.data;            
            x = data['x']
            x_filter = data['x_filter']
            y = data['y']

            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if(x_filter[i] == radio_value) {
                    x[i] = x_filter[i];
                } else {
                    x[i] = undefined;
                }
            }
        source.change.emit();
        """)

# option
option = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["One", "Two", "Three"],
                          active=0, callback=callback)
show(column(widgetbox(option),p))
```

The interesting code is in JavaScript. Basically, it checks for each point if the point's x coordinate equals your RadioButton selection. If it doesn't, the point is set to missing. This makes the point disappear in the plot. A new column `x_filter` is added to your data. It is used for comparing the Radio choice to your original x. The actual `x` is used for plotting.

Comment: Thank you so much. This code worked...partially.. my graph does not refresh itself after I click the radio button. I have to drag the graph and then dots will show correctly. Do you know the reason? Thanks

Comment: Which bokeh version are you using? I tested with 0.12.6. It should at least work with anything newer than that, I guess. What browser are you using? You should also try using a different one.

Comment: Thank you mc51! I updated my Bokeh to 0.12.7 and the issue solved. Thanks again